# event.target in SVG padding?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have an `SVG` that 'm using as a drawing surface. It contains all sorts of sub-elements, and in this case, the one I care about is a `circle`. In an effort to be able to draw all the way to the edge of the `svg`, I've added `padding: 5px` to the `svg` element, which works as intended, with one small wrinkle.

Click events on a `circle` in the `svg` element itself return `event.target.nodeName == circle`. But click events on a `circle` in the padding returns `event.target.nodeName == svg`, which effectively makes the `circle` unselectable (since I can't click it). Is there a way to see the actual `event.target` within an element's padding like this? Or do I need to build a workaround (i.e. mapping the coordinates of the circles I've placed, and checking the `svg`'s `event.currentTarget` against those coordinates each time)?

Updated: Here's a fiddle illustrating the issue. Click the left circle (inside the padding) and `event.target.nodeName == svg`; click the right circle (in the svg proper) and `event.target.nodeName == circle`.

https://jsfiddle.net/r5jd87n6/2/

Comment: I am curious if you add the css `box-sizing: border-box;` to the `svg` element if you'd get the results you expect?

Comment: for that matter, a minimal complete js example would be a great way to get meaningful answers.

Comment: Please add  a [mcve] to the question.

Comment: WFM on Firefox providing I add overflow:visible to the <svg> element.

Comment: @RobertLongson well would you look at that; WFM also. Want to add as an answer, and I'll mark as a working solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work OK at least on Firefox once I add overflow: visible to the outer `<svg>` element.

```js
$('#parentsvg').click(function(event){
 $('#output').html("event.target.nodeName: " + event.target.nodeName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <svg id="parentsvg" width="200" height="200" style="padding:15px; overflow:visible" >
    <circle id="clickableCircle" cx="100" cy="50" r="6" fill="#333333"></circle>
    <circle id="unClickableCircle" cx="-5" cy="50" r="6" fill="#333333"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>

</div>
```